# Tomcat 6.x - Deploy only required WAR files

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, deployment, war

We use Tomcat 6.x version for our development.  We have 6 applications that deploy as separate WARs.  Thus, each time TOMCAT boots, it deploys 6 WARs.

I want to be able to tell Tomcat (manually or otherwise) which WARs have changed and deploy only those, while for others, the old deployed exploded folder structure needs to be reused.

Is this possible?  If yes, how?  I did Google a bit, but couldn't find a solution.

Thanks,
Siddharth

EDIT - One thing I found while Googling is that once a WAR is deployed, we can remove the WAR while keeping the exploded folder.  Thus, it won't be deployed next time.  I am yet to try this approach.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by “deploy”? Tomcat is not expanding already expanded WAR file. Moreover expanding (i.e. unpacking) WAR is usually a quick operation. The most time consuming is actual initialization of the application that must be done each time you restart Tomcat.

Comment: By deploy, I mean the WAR file being exploded and initialized.

Comment: Well, you can’t skip initialization after restart. However, why are you restarting Tomcat anyway? Just remove the WAR from appBase directory (`${CATALINA_HOME}/webapps`), Tomcat will undeploy it (and remove its expanded files), then put a new WAR file here and Tomcat will deploy it. If not then check out if you have enabled autoDeploy in server.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Manually you can tell tomcat to redeploy using the Tomcat Manager. There are options for each web-app like start, stop and reload. You can hit reload for the war files that are changed..